# Convex curve has convex interior

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

> Let $c: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a simple closed curve with curvature $\kappa \geq 0$.
>
> Then the interior of $c$ is convex.

I know that in this case
$$
\langle N(t_0), c(t) - c(t_0) \rangle \geq 0 \quad \text{for all}\; t, t_0 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

But how do I obtain that $\text{Int}(c)$ is convex from there?